# What is the cubic foot capacity of my Maytag washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine

My washing machine is over 21 years old.

I am going to buy a new one with a larger   capacity but I don't know the cubic ft capacity of mine.

It is  a Maytag MAV6057AWW.

Answer (score -1):

From a  Google search   [this website](https://www.justanswer.com/appliance/1qmok-tub-capacity-cubic-ft-mav6057aww.html) says, about 2.9 cu.ft.

As Ed Beal suggested,  the washer is listed as being 3.1 cu.ft. but usable size is 2.9.  *Added in case link is not read or works.*

Comment: Since the link states that that model is 3.1 cu ft you should suggest searching for one larger than that. All manufactures play the same games with actual size vs usable size of 2.9 in that answer. If the op got a 3.1 thinking it would be larger and ended up with the same size it would not be a very good answer based on that link alone. Revise for the larger size and it would be worth an up vote.